# SELECT IN with empty sub query, gives weird result

Tags: mysql

I have to following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` IN
        (
            SELECT `table1_id` FROM `table2` WHERE `id` in 
            (
                SELECT `table2_id` FROM `table3` WHERE `customer_id` = 57
            )
        )
```

It returns 10 rows (from 50)
but the query

```
SELECT `table1_id` FROM `table2` WHERE `id` in 
    (
        SELECT `table2_id` FROM `table3` WHERE `customer_id` = 57
    )
```

returns 0 rows (which is correct). 
So how come that my first query returns several rows while it should returns 0 (like the subquery).

If I use a customer_id that should return rows on the second query everything goes as is should be.

So my question is why do:
Why does the query returns rows while the subquery does not?

Comment: Couldn't you just join to `table2`,`table3` and implement the `customer_id` in a `WHERE` instead of nesting multiple subqueries?

Comment: @Abhi This isn't a correlated subquery.

Comment: If this is really happening, it sounds like a bug. Can you provide some sample data that demonstrates it?

Comment: Try to avoid `WHERE IN (SELECT ...)`. Even when it gets the correct answer, MySQL often implements it very inefficiently -- queries that take a fraction of a second with a `JOIN` can take minutes with `WHERE IN`.

Comment: you probably have some null values in table1 table1_id. just a guess. as people said: try to aviod subqueries in favor of joins.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu Why would that cause it to return those rows? `NULL` should never match anything when used in `IN()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the same query avoiding in clause

check for resul

```
  SELECT DISTINCT `table1`.* 
  FROM `table1` 
  INNER JOIN `table2` ON  `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`table1_id`
  INNER JOIN `table3` ON `table2`.`id` =  `table3`.`table2_id` 
    and  `table3`.`customer_id` = 57
```

Comment: Change it to `SELECT DISTINCT table1.*`. Otherwise it returns all the columns from the other two tables, and it returns the same row multiple times if there are multiple matches.